# Coverflow animation stutter in looped carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

I am trying to build a carousel that somewhat resembles the coverflow effect macOS used to have long back. I have used [Swiper Js](https://swiperjs.com/) as the base for the carousel. Well the implementation  looks right for my requirement and does the job until reaching the last slide (where cloning of slides start). The moment it reaches the last slide and then goes to the first one or vice-versa, there is a visible delay and stutter in the animation. I am absolutely at my wits end as to how to get this fixed. I am using swiper because of the amount of customisation it provides. Another thing is i need the carousel to be responsive(the mobile version is pretty different from the desktop version, and i have done the mobile version without a problem). There is a coverflow effect built in with the library, but that doesnt work well the moment I fix the width of each slide and set the number of slides visible. The intended behaviour for the carousel to switch slides is either by keyboard or by clicking the respective slides.

Here is what i have tried and achieved so far -

**HTML**

```
<div class="coverflow-carousel">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="carousel-card">
                <figure>
                    <img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4>Hello World</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        .....
        .....
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.coverflow-carousel {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .swiper-slide {
        perspective: 800px;
        perspective-origin: center;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
        &:not(.swiper-slide-visible) {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .carousel-card {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 320px;
            color: #fff;
            background: #292a34;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            figure {
                text-align: center;
                img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                    width: 120px;
                    height: auto;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: 10px auto;
                }
                figcaption {
                    padding: 0 10px;
                    p {
                        font-size: 13px;
                        line-height: 1.4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
const slider = $('.coverflow-carousel');

// just adding some number to the names to distinguish
slider.find('.swiper-slide').each((i, elem) => {
  $(elem).find('h4').html(`Hello World ${i}`);
});


let carousel = new Swiper('.coverflow-carousel', {
  init: false,
  loop: true,
  speed: 300,
  initialSlide: 0,
  slidesPerView: 6,
  centeredSlides: true,
  grabCursor: false,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true
  },
  a11y: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    dynamicBullets: true,
    clickable: true
  },
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  simulateTouch: false,
  shortSwipes: false,
  longSwipes: false,
  loopAdditionalSlides: 20,
  on: {
    init: function () {
      // add transition style
      // slider.find('.swiper-slide').css({
      //   'transition': 'opacity 0.4s ease-in-out'
      // });
    },
  },
});

carousel.on('init slideChangeTransitionStart', () => {
  let slide = slider.find('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-visible');

  let width = slider.find('.swiper-slide').width();

  let margin = (320 - width) * 0.5; // the 320 is the width of the slide desired

  slider.find('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-visible > .carousel-card').css({
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });

  slide.eq(0).css('z-index', 2).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.7) translateX(45%) rotateY(30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
  slide.eq(1).css('z-index', 3).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.8) translateX(20%) rotateY(30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
  slide.eq(2).css('z-index', 4).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.9) translateX(5%) rotateY(30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
  slide.eq(3).css('z-index', 5).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(1) translateX(0) rotateY(0)'
  });
  slide.eq(4).css('z-index', 4).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.9) translateX(-5%) rotateY(-30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
  slide.eq(5).css('z-index', 3).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) rotateY(-30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
  slide.eq(6).css('z-index', 2).find('.carousel-card').css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.7) translateX(-45%) rotateY(-30deg)',
    'margin-left': `-${margin}px`
  });
});


carousel.init();


slider.on('click', '.carousel-card', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let index = $(this).closest('.swiper-slide').data('swiper-slide-index');
  
  carousel.slideToLoop(index);
});
```

Here is the link to the codepen as well -> https://codepen.io/dajasra/full/BajwrJY

Please help !

Note: i have checked old threads here regarding other libraries to get inspiration from, but most of them are dead threads with dead links in them.